# Trying to Get mean from an object column (Pandas-Python) But getting TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the StackOverflow developer survey 2020. There's a column 'YearsCode'. For how many years you have been coding? The data type of this column is  'object'. I am trying to find the mean value from this column. I have tried following steps but found an error--

```
df['YearsCode'].unique() # here I found 'less than 1 year', 'more than 50 years'.
df['YearsCode'].replace('Less than 1 year',0,inplace = True)
df['YearsCode'].replace('More than 50 years',51,inplace = True) 
df['YearsCode'].astype(float)
# to avoid nan values we will use skipna
df['YearsCode'].mean(skipna=False) 
# returns---TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str   
#if I make NaN values to 0, by mean will not be right
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `df['YearsCode'].astype(float)` statement has not effect, since it wasn't done "inplace". It returns a series, but doesn't change the original values of `df['YearsCode']`

Try:

```py
df['YearsCode'] = df['YearsCode'].astype(float)
df['YearsCode'].mean(skipna=False)
```

or simply:

```py
df['YearsCode'].astype(float).mean(skipna=False)
```

On the first time, I replaced the original "YearsCode" column with the float type "YearsCode". On the second time, I calculated the `.mean()` directly over float type "YearsCode".

Comment: I have done this -  df['YearsCode'] =  pd.to_numeric(df['YearsCode'],errors = 'coerce')